# Why doesn't Tennessee have a tether attached during his EVA?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In *[Alien: Covenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant_)*, a stellar neutrino burst damages the ship. Tennessee comes out of the ship to fix the damage, but he has no tether, the way normal astronauts have.

[image]

Why doesn't Tennessee have a tether here?

Comment: Feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: Do you mean normal as per the Alien franchise, or normal as per real life?  Because if it is the latter your question is based on a flawed assumption.  The first real world un-tethered space walk was made in 1984 by Bruce McCandless See [this article](https://newatlas.com/first-astronaut-untethered-dies/52738/) about him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The novelisation indicates that he doesn't need a tether. His suit is kitted out with "propulsors" that can return him to the ship in the event that he wants to do so and the purpose of his EVA (to roam around the outside looking for damage) would seem to obviate the need to be tethered to any one specific point.

> Activating his suit propulsors, he pivoted back toward the bulk of the
> Covenant. One thing about doing EVA outside a colony ship, he told
> himself. You couldn’t lose track of your home base, because there was
> absolutely no other possible destination within a light year. He let
> Ankor know he was okay.
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien: Covenant - Official Novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien:_Covenant_(novel))</sup></sub>

Theoretically he *could* float off if his suit's propulsion is damaged, but another person in a suit could just get him. There's nowhere else for him to go.